# How many numbers are less than million such that their digits sum is $\le 19$?

Tags: calculus, functions, generating-functions

> How many numbers are less than million such that their digits sum is $\le 19$?

This question is a Generating-Functions exercise.

The solution claims the answer is the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in:

$$ \left( 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^9 \right)^6 \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) $$

The left term is obvious, but why multiplying by $\frac{1}{1-x}$?

In general, if $F(x)$ generates $a_n$ then $\frac{F(x)}{1-x}$ generates $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n a_k$, but I don't see is that fitting here.

Comment: Without that term, the coefficient of $x^{19}$ would be the numbers less than a million whose digit sum is _exactly_ $19$.

Comment: @TonyK, Could you expand your answer? Why is it working in that way?

Comment: It was you who said that the left term is obvious! What did you mean by that?

Comment: You rihgt my friend, I guess I didn't understand it completly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been hinted in a comment, but if
$$F(x) = (1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 +x ^6 + x^7 + x^8 + x^9)^6,$$
then the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in $F(x)$ 
is the number of non-negative integers less than $10^6$
for which the sum of digits of the integer's decimal representation is *exactly* $19.$

But you want the sum of digits to be *at most* $19,$ so you want
the sum of coefficients of the first twenty terms of $F(x)$
(that is, terms where the exponent of $x$ ranges from $0$ to $19$),
which as you already know is the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the
series representation of $\dfrac{F(x)}{1 - x}.$

Comment: right. Thank you @David K

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some code in java to brute force this problem, and I got the answer 147,070. I'll put the code below.

(NOTE: Now I noticed that this doesn't exactly answer your question, but I'll just leave it in case it's helpful to somebody at some point in time.)

```
public class million {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       int x = 0;
       int counter = 0;

       while (x < 1000000) {
           int test = x;
           int sum = 0;

           while (test > 0) {
                sum += test % 10;
                test = test / 10;
            }

           if (sum <= 19) {
               counter += 1;
           }    

       x += 1;
       }

       System.out.println(counter);
   }
}
```

Comment: While that's probably true, this is not the answer to the actual question (why the multiplication with $\frac{1}{1-x}$. -1

Comment: @naslundx oh you're right, I didn't see that part. Now I guess the question is should I delete my answer or take the downvotes like a man?

Comment: @jj172 I think that this does answer one of the two questions that were asked. Actually to me it is a better answer than just "the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the following expression". Don't feel discouraged because someone downvoted your answer, there are other people like me, who value computational answers like this one just as much as a more theoretical one.

Comment: It is good to be able to work a problem an alternative way in order to check the answer. This is an alternative way, and therefore has some value.